# Error when trying to connect to MySQL DB using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I am using the Docker. I have Apache, PHP, MySQL installed. When I use Adminer through Docker, I can login to my DB. When I use mysqli in my code. I get this

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/html/temp_log.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/html/temp_log.php on line 8
Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 2002 Debugging error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

This is the command I use:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);
```

Where server is the container name. In my case "nv_db", user is root and db is the name I used.

This is my docker setup

[image]

Please, could you advice?

Comment: did you use port 3310 specifically in your `mysqli` connection?

Comment: port 3310 is not the default port for MySQL so either specify the port number on the `$mysqli = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db,3310);` or change `mysqli.default_port = 3306` in the `php.ini` to 3310

Comment: I tried that. But it doesn't work. The same error message.